# C++ initializing an object that contains another object design issue

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments, pass-by-reference, lvalue

I am attempting to write two classes `A` and `B` where `B` contains an instance of class `A`. In practice, `A` contains some large data. In this toy example, let's assume they are as follow:

```
class A{
public:
    int a;
    A(){}
    A(const A& ac){
       cout <<"copy constructor for A" << endl;
       a = ac.a;
    }
    virtual ~A(){}
    A& operator=(const A& that){
      cout <<"operator = for A" << endl;
      a = that.a;
      return *this;
   }
};
class B{
private:
    A ba;
public:
    B(){  a = A();  }
    B(A& a){
        cout << "Using default constructor" << endl;
        ba = a;
    }
    B(const B& copy){
        cout<<"copy"<< endl; ba = copy.ba;
    }
    B& operator=( const B& that){
       cout<<"invoking operator = "<< k<< endl;
       ba = that.ba;
       return *this;
    }
    virtual ~B(){}
    A& getA(){ return ba; }
    void printAadrr(){
        cout << &ba <<" "<< ba.a<< endl;
    }
};
```

The problem with this is that when initializing `B` using `B::B(A& a)`, the argument is copied into the instance `ba` in `B`. It might be inefficient if `a` is large.

I thought of another approach where instead of

```
class B{
private:
    A ba;
    ....
```

I could do

```
class B{
    private:
        A* ba;
public:
    B(){  
       ba = new A(); //but we have to free memory in destructor if we call default constructor
    }
    B(A& a){
        cout << "Using default constructor" << endl;
        ba = &a;
    }
```

But this design choice has its own issue where if I make `B` by default constructor, I need to free the memory allocated for `ba` later on in the destructor.

Is there a convenient way to pass the "reference" of the object `A` (created outside of `B`) into `B` in the constructor if we use `B::B(A& a)` and create an empty, default `A` object if we use B::B()? I tried

```
B::B(A& a){
    &ba = &a;
}
```

but it gives "lvalue has to be on the left of assignment" error.

Any advice is appreciated. Sorry for the overly long post.

Comment: C++11 provides _rvalue references_ along with `std::move` to make your intentions clear.  That is useful if you want to _transfer_ `A` into `B`.  Otherwise you are free to store a reference to the external object.  But you must use initializer lists in the constructor, not direct assignment.  Or you can use `std::reference_wrapper`.  Beware storing references in objects, because you may have issues with object lifetime.

Comment: uhmn... thanks for the "pointer". I wasn't aware of `std::move` or `std::reference_wrapper`. I will read up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a constructor using move semantics as follows:

```
B::B( A && a )
: ba( std::move( a ) )
{}
```

Now you can transfer an instance into the object.

```
A a;
B b( std::move( a ) );
// `b` stores content of `a`, and local `a` is no longer valid.
```

You can still construct with the copy constructor if you *want*.

```
A a;
B b( a );
// `b` stores a copy of `a`, and local `a` is still valid.
```

Comment: ahhh awesome! this is what I am looking for

Comment: I just corrected my answer.  It was not a move constructor.  A move constructor would have been `B::B( B && b )`.

Comment: i see. i have just started reading up on these move semantic. i am fairly new to c++11

Comment: @Tuan333 For this to work you need to make sure that `A` is movable. Either by explicitly writing a move constructor and move assignment operator. Or preferably by [meeting the criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions) for the compiler to generate the functions for you. As `A` is written above a move constructor will not be generated for you as you have explicity declared a copy constructor. Also, be warned that Visual Studio versions before 2015 would not generate a move constructor for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having A as a simple member var, have a pointer to A. Then when constructing B, just pass a pointer to an instance of A.

```
class B{
private:
    A* ba;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is my second approach, which has its own issue as indicated in the question

Comment: In this approach, since you have a pointer to A in B, you *should* NOT be creating object A from within B. The whole point of having a pointer is that it can hold a link to something in memory that has already been created by another part of the program. In this case, A would already have been instantiated in the main method. I am not sure if that suits your design.

Comment: Yes, `A` should be initiated in the main method, but in the case of default constructor, I won't have a readily made `A` object in the main method, hence I had to look for a *robust* approach to make `B` regardless of where `A` comes from.

Comment: Ok understood. I think it is better to initialize A* to null if you don't have an instance. Also, check for null before using A* anywhere as a safe-guard. Its all about trade-offs :)

Comment: Ahhh good point. I thought of `NULL` as well, but was a bit hesitant to use it since precisely the reason you mentioned (checking for safe-guard everywhere). I intended to use this approach if nothing in SO yields valid answer. +1 for your thoughtfulness though.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your design. In case you want `B` own `A` use `std::move` to obtain `A` by `B`.

In general case use `std::shared_ptr` which will manage memory by itself. After all instances of `std::shared_ptr<A>` will be destroyed, then `A` data will be deleted too. But in this case `B` instances can **share** same `A` data.

Other solution is `std::unique_ptr` but you have to move it every time you copy `B` what means that ownership of `A` will be transferred same as `std::move` solution.